# paydaycap paydaycapVH junk logins

Tags: security, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9, spam

[Screenshot of Admin => Customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcfqa.png)

[image]

Strange Activities : I am getting lots of junk account creation on my magento website. This leads to lot of bounced emails, and hurting my domain authority.

I regularly ban ip addresses who access open ports of magento randomly. I am thinking of capturing ip addresses while they create account and ban those ip addresses as-well.

How to stop these Junk users / Spammers ?

Comment: Can any one please help me, how to capture ip address of a customer, while they create account. IP address should show up in admin area.

Comment: Can you send the screenshot of your signup page ? I think the bots are easily making sign up through your homepage.

Comment: its saree(dot)com , please check.

Comment: I see you have not added captcha on login page, so it's one security vulnerability. Please go through my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow below steps :

1. Install [McAFee Secure](https://marketplace.magento.com/mcafeesecure-module-mcafeesecure.html) to Your website & Have your website Pass the Security Checks
2. Enable Magento Default Captcha [Follow this Steps](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/magento-captcha.html)

*OR*  Install [ReCaptcha Plugin](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) to Your Frontend's Registration & Login Page

*OR* Install Magento Extension for Captcha : [Simpler Captcha](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simpler-captcha.html)

3. Enable Captcha to Your Administrator Login. [Follow this Steps](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/magento1/adding-captcha-protection-to-a-magento-site?_ga=1.71510806.468929724.1490188304).
4. (Optional) Enable SSL on Magento. [Follow this Steps](https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/magento1/enabling-ssl-for-magento).

Hope this will definitely help you.

Comment: I will try captcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried captcha, sure it did help. But then customer registration dropped. 
So I did some research and found that those accounts were made from Russian ip addresses. I downloaded the data of complete russian IP addresses. And denied them under .htaccess file.